# is it possible to create an in-memory file and access it with FileInfo?

Tags: c#, file-io, fileinfo

I want to FTP a file, and I am using the FileInfo class for certain things.

Would it be possible to create an in-memory file and initialize FileInfo with it?

How could I then write the file to disk if I wanted to afterwards?

Comment: What exactly do you need from the `FileInfo` object? Most of the properties and methods it has exists as static methods as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. FileInfo's constructor will only expect a path, not a stream. I think your going to want to use the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) class...

Answer (score 1):

No, FileInfo only works against things on the filesystem. Why not create the file in a temp directory, then move it to its final destination as needed? `Path.GetTempFileName` and `Path.GetTempPath` may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with a RAM disk if you want to have the benefits - look for instance at this article at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows). 
I am personally using Superdisk because I use an app which writes exentsive logs and I gained a performance by using it, but if you have control I would think twice about adding this external dependency.

Comment: A RAM Disk is also using a filesystem, what mrblah is searching for is writing a file on a volatile memory space.